# OK to use non-OEM/aftermarket camshaft position sensor?

Tags: starting, ignition, parts

I have a 2002 2.4L 4cyl Mitsubishi Galant with the error code to replace the camshaft position sensor. The car is having starting issues common with a faulty cam sensor. I know where the sensor is, and should be able to replace it myself.

I have just begun to do my own car repairs, and I am wondering how important it is that for a camshaft position sensor, I choose the OEM part instead of a much cheaper "replacement" or knockoff?

To clarify, this is not a "please link me" shopping question, this is asking about the legitimacy of using non-OEM/aftermarket cam sensors and if it is something that one should ever consider.

Comment: UPDATE: I ordered and replaced it myself and everything is up and running great :) Ended up using a beck/arnley part

Comment: Go for it. The only things you shouldn't skimp on are belts and brakes. The rest you can take a risk on and buy something cheaper. That being said, Bosch usually makes better quality parts that are cheaper than OEM.

Answer (score 3):

Although this question can raise differing opinions the very basic answer is yes you can use non OEM parts. In some cases they offer better warranties than the OEM brand. Aftermarket parts are in general made to the same specifications as the OEM part. You do want to be careful with your sources of aftermarket parts. Buy only parts from reputable suppliers. If a web based search of a particular brand reveals they don't have a website or only a single distributor I would be suspicious.

Comment: I would like to add to this excellent answer, that when you deal with aftermarket parts, you will become familiar with brands which you will start to trust and look for when searching for parts.

Comment: Thanks guys, both great pieces of info exactly along the lines of what I was looking for.

Comment: I was just thinking of something in particular ... You can get an aftermarket sunroof/moonroof put into your car which will look and behave *exactly* like an OEM. The difference will be the OEM will only be warranted for the period of the bumper-to-bumper warranty, while the aftermarket one will be warranted for the life of the auto. One case where aftermarket is far superior to OEM.